# Animate drawableLeft APNG in button?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add an animated PNG to a Button as a drawableLeft.

Basically, the button begins its life disabled and unclickable with animated PNG of a 16x16 indeterminate progress icon.

- If I can grab a cached location from the GPS, the button becomes enabled & clickable and has its text set to the latitude & longitude I was able to grab from the cache.
- Once the GPS gets a lock, the animated icon gets replaced by a checkmark, the button becomes enabled & clickable (if it wasn't already), and the button's Text gets set to the new latitude & longitude.

The idea is that the user can be impatient and click the button immediately to accept the cached value, or stick around and wait for a better value to appear.

So much for the theory. I tried it with an APNG that I know beyond doubt to be valid (the bouncing beachball from the APNG wikipedia article), as well as several other APNG images, but none of them animate when I embed them in the button.

Is this even possible? Do I somehow need to trigger the animation? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APNG format is not currently supported.   An issue was opened and declined with google asking for support http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7743.  And there is a second open issue requesting support http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?q=apng&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=10273

I wouldn't anticipate this being added any time soon.

I would look into using an AnimationDrawable for what you want to do http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: Oops. I could have *sworn* I saw an article somewhere that said APNG was Android's official animated-image format for things like indeterminate progress indicators, but I'll take your word for it. That said, do you happen to know whether it's possible to hijack any of Android's built-in animations (like spinner_black_16, I believe) for the purpose?